# Как вывести в HTML первую строку содержания файла в качестве названия

Tags: php

Всем здравствуйте. Вот есть такой код и несколько файлов txt. Этот код выводит название файлов на страничку HTML. А как вместо названия файлов выводить первую строчку их содержимого? Спасибо всем, кто сможет помочь. Только, пожалуйста, регулярки использовать нельзя.

```
 <?php
        if ($handle = opendir(ROOT_DIR . '/articles')) {
            while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
                if ($entry !='.' and $entry !='..'){
                    echo '<li><a href="index.php?show='.$entry.'">'.$entry.'</a></li>';//показывать содержимое файла

    }}
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: Начните уже читать php мануалы.

Comment: Если можете, посоветуйте хороший и понятный. Чтобы с объяснениями...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ($handle = opendir(ROOT_DIR . '/articles')) {
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($entry != '.' and $entry != '..') {
            $file_text = file_get_contents(ROOT_DIR . '/articles/' . $entry);
            list($first_str) = explode("\n", $file_text);
            echo '<li><a href="index.php?show=' . $entry . '">' . $first_str . '</a></li>';//показывать содержимое файла
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. А можно сделать без list?

Comment: да,  `$strs = explode("\n", $file_text); echo $strs[0];`

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Все работает!

Comment: @ОлисияМедведева рад помочь

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  if ($handle = opendir(ROOT_DIR . '/articles')) {
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
      if ($entry !='.' and $entry !='..'){
        $firstLineInFile = file("{$handle}/{$entry}")[0];
        echo "
          <li>
            файл - {$entry}
            <ul>
              <li>
                первая строка из файла {$firstLineInFile} 
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>";
      }
    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Говорит, что не может найти файл txt.